# How do I host Laravel and Inertiajs (React) app in cPanel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, npm

I built a laravel with inertiajs App, Now I'm going to deploy my app to some host.

I tried Siteground to deploy it but it doesn't support NPM!

Now I'm trying to do it with cpannel, Here is my file structure:
[image]

And I already connect SSH terminal. there is no issue with laravel installation, but when I do `npm install` I'm getting `-bash: npm: command not found`

Can you help me with some example please!

Answer (score 2):

In production you don't need to install node modules if you have a production version of your (React app)

i usually use Reactjs in frontend so the process is

1. `yarn build`
2. take the build version of your app and add it to the root of your server

for Laravel

1. `git clone ******`
2. `cp .env.example .env`
3. edit the .env data to match your production data
4. run `composer install`
5. run `php artisan key:generate`
6. `php artisan migrate`
7. point your server to the public folder with symbolic link for example

your app should now be live.